# How to call a UIViewController inside a UIButton in swift NSCoder

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I don't know how call a `UIViewController` inside a `UIButton`.

I have this ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

private var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView
private var label: UILabel

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    label = UILabel()
    activity = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

.....

And in another file the calling like this:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var pointer = ExampleViewController(coder: NSCoder)


}
```

I don't know what I should write in NSCoder in this case. If I write ExampleViewController(), Xcode shows an error **"Missing argument for parameter coder in call"**. 
I suppose I don't understand something but I don't have a lot of experience so I will appreciate some information about that.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you want to use NSCoder to initialize the controller?

Comment: Move those two lines out of `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and into `viewDidLoad()`:
`label = UILabel()
 activity = UIActivityIndicatorView()`

Get rid of `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.
Call your View Controller like so 
`var pointer = ExampleViewController()`

BTW, generally speaker Swift doesn't know the concept of pointers unless in very specific cases derived from C or so. So are creating a var of type ExampleViewController rather than a pointer.

Comment: Thanks to both but If I write this: class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    private var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView
    private var label: UILabel
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        label = UILabel()
        activity = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    } Swift shiow a error message "Class ExampleViewController has no initializers and if write the initializer, like    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
Swift shows Property self.activity not inizialitzed at super.ini call.